# ${\rm W/m}^2$ to Jansky

Tags: light, observational-astronomy, magnitude, units

Lets assume I have a source and receive $8 \times 10^{-20}$ ${\rm Wm}^{-2}$ in (400-750) nm filter. How do you convert this received flux to the unit Jansky, is there a formula? (Ultimately, I want to express this flux in magnitude AB.)

Comment: Just check the Wikipedia page for the Jansky: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky

Comment: Your source has a given flux in [energy/time], but Jansky is a measure of flux _density_ in [energy/time/frequency bin] or, equivalently, [energy/time/wavelength bin]. Have a look at the link given by Phiteros, and the answer to the question [Conversion of magnitudes to Jansky and MAGPHYS](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12541/5264), which I think is so close to your question that I'm actually voting to close yours as a duplicate.